# Python Superglobal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there is a super global (like PHP) in Python?  I have certain variables I want to use throughout my whole project in separate files, classes, and functions, and I don't want to have to keep declaring it throughout each file.

Comment: Since you don't "declare" anything, do you mean "reference" or "import"?  Could you clarify what you're doing that's causing a problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In theory yes, you can start spewing crud into __builtin__:

```
>>> import __builtin__
>>> __builtin__.rubbish= 3
>>> rubbish
3
```

But, don't do this; it's horrible evilness that will give your applications programming-cancer.

> classes and functions and i don't want to have to keep declaring

Put them in modules and ‘import’ them when you need to use them.

> I have certain variables i want to use throughout my whole project

If you must have unqualified values, just put them in a file called something like “mypackage/constants.py” then:

```
from mypackage.constants import *
```

If they really are ‘variables’ in that you change them during app execution, you need to start encapsulating them in objects.

Comment: Using `from mypackage.constants import *` is almost as bad as monkeypatching `__builtin__`—it has the same net effect of destroying the use of namespaces. The right advice is what you gave: "Put them in modules and ‘import’ them when you need to use them." This is not a point we should be flexible on, since it hurts readability, flexibility, predictability, and explicitness of our programs.

Comment: @Mike: Normally `from module import nonmodulething` is indeed highly undesirable, but for the specific case of symbolic constants I think the case may be arguable. Typing the full path to `mypackage.constants.THINGTYPE_SOMETHING` in every usage is too long. Sure, there are other, potentially better approaches, but in this case the potential harm would be fairly minimal.

Comment: I'm not talking about `from module import nonmodulething`, which is perfectly sane. I'm talking about `from module import *`, which is always insane and makes your program impossible to fully understand from reading your source code file. The difference between `from m import o` and `from m import *` is the difference from taking a book off your shelf and knocking your shelf down.

Comment: +1 "it's horrible evilness that will give your applications programming-cancer" What a turn of phrase!

Comment: This is useful when I use Python in IDA debugger and need to change execution flow in a breakpoint, depending on its hit count. I've learned a long time ago to stop saying "never do this" - there's *always* a plausible use case.

Comment: For Python3 you can use `builtins` instead of `__builtin__`. This is a great feature for debuggin, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Create empty superglobal.py module.
In your files do:

```
import superglobal
superglobal.whatever = loacalWhatever
other = superglobal.other
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer. I tested personally and it is a short but valuable answer.

Answer (score 4):

Even if there are, you should not use such a construct EVER. Consider using a borg pattern to hold this kind of stuff.

```
class Config:
    """
    Borg singlton config object
    """
    __we_are_one = {}
    __myvalue = ""

    def __init__(self):
        #implement the borg patter (we are one)
        self.__dict__ = self.__we_are_one

    def myvalue(self, value=None):
        if value:
           self.__myvalue = value
        return self.__myvalue

conf = Config()
conf.myvalue("Hello")
conf2 = Config()
print conf2.myvalue()
```

Here we use the borg pattern to create a singlton object. No matter where you use this in the code, the 'myvalue' will be the same, no matter what module or class you instantiate Config in.

Comment: -1 for using double underscores. That needlessy invokes name mangling. If you mean private, use a single underscore instead.

Comment: You are SOOO wrong here. A single underscore (as per the Pep 8 document) is a weak indicato that the value can not be imported in a 'from x import *' and a double underscore makes it class private via name mangling, just as I intended.

Comment: For example:

>>> class A:
...   _var1 = "hello"
...   __var2 = "hello2"
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a._var1
'hello'
>>> a.__var2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute '__var2'
>>>

Comment: Obviously, the last comment formatted poorly, so I will just explain:

If I have a class, and I want a variable to be class private, I MUST use double underscores to make that happen. A single underscore does NOT make that variable class private.

Comment: Your example is broken. Last line prints empty string, because `__init__` always resets self.__myvalue.

Comment: Singletons are euphamisms for globals. **They are not your friends!** Globals/Singletons should be used extremely judiciously; take this post for an example of how to do this without creating complicated constructs like this in the first place http://glyf.livejournal.com/70684.html

Comment: Your use of a `myvalue` gettersetter and a `__myvalue` name-mangled attribute seem like a pretty nonstandard, nonidiomatic Python. `myvalue` has a pretty weird API, seemingly attempting to look like method overloading, which isn't really something people expect like they would in C++. I also avoid `__foo` attributes, as they don't make data private, but they do make code harder to work with, test, understand, and subclass.

Answer (score 4):

in years of practice, i've grown quite disappointed with python's import system: it is complicated and difficult to handle correctly. also, i have to maintain scores of imports in each and every module i write, which is a pita.

namespaces are a very good idea, and they're indispensable---php doesn't have proper namespaces, and it's a mess.

conceptually, part of writing an application consists in defining a suitable vocabulary, the words that you'll use to do the things you want to. yet in the classical way, it's exactly these words that won't come easy, as you have to first import this, import that to obtain access.

when namespaces came into focus in the javascript community, john resig of jquery fame decided that providing a single `$` variable in the global namespace was the way to go: it would only affect the global namespace minimally, and provide easy access to everything with jquery.

likewise, i experimented with a global variable `g`, and it worked to an extent. basically, you have two options here: either have a startup module that must be run prior to any other module in your app, which defines what things should be available in `g`, so it is ready to go when needed. the other approach which i tried was to make `g` lazy and to react with custom imports when a new name was required; so whenever you need to `g.foo.frob(42)` for the first time, the mechanism will try something like `import foo; g.foo = foo` behind the scenes. that was considerable more difficult to do right.

these days, i've ditched the import system almost completely except for standard library and site packages. most of the time i write wrappers for hose libraries, as 90% of those have inanely convoluted interfaces anyhow. those wrappers i then publish in the global namespace, using spelling conventions to keep the risk of collisions to a minimum.

i only tell this to alleviate the impression that modifying the global namespace is something that is inherently evil, which the other answers seem to state. not so. what is evil is to do it thoughtlessly, or be compelled by language or package design to do so.

let me add one remark, as i almost certainly will get some fire here: 99% of all imports done by people who religiously defend namespace purity are *wrong*. proof? you'll read in the beginning lines of any module `foo.py` that needs to do trigonometrics something like `from math import sin`. now when you correctly `import foo` and have a look at that namespace, what are you going to find? something named `foo.sin`. but that `sin` isn't part of the interface of `foo`, it is just a helper, it shouldn't clutter that namespace---hence, `from math import sin as _sin` or somesuch would've been correct. however, almost nobody does it that way.

i'm sure to arouse some heated comments with these views, so go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it wasn't obvious to you is that Python intentionally doesn't try to support such a thing. Namespaces are a *feature*, and using them is to your advantage. If you want something you defined in another file, import it. This means from reading your source code you can figure out where everything came from, and also makes your code easier to test and modify.