# Python borg pattern problem

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm having problems implementing a borg in python. I found an example in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736335/python-superglobal) but it's not working for me, unless I'm missing something. Here's the code:

```
class Config:
    """
    Borg singleton config object
    """
    __we_are_one = {}
    __myvalue = ""

    def __init__(self):
        #implement the borg pattern (we are one)
        self.__dict__ = self.__we_are_one
        self.__myvalue = ""

    def myvalue(self, value=None):
        if value:
           self.__myvalue = value
        return self.__myvalue

conf = Config()
conf.myvalue("Hello")
conf2 = Config()
print conf2.myvalue()
```

I assume this is meant to print "Hello", but for me it just prints a blank line. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Why are you using double __ names for your attributes?  A single leading _ will do to make it "private".

Comment: Well I copied the code from the other question that I linked to. But anyway, I thought a single _ hinted that it is private, whereas a double _ causes name mangling which is an even stronger hint that it *really* is private, although it can still be accessed if the user is determined.

Comment: No! Single leading underscores will NOT make them private, only make it so that module level variables are not imported on 'from foo import *' Otherwise, it has no effect other than to 'hint' at privacy.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I corrected the other example.

Comment: Name mangling isn't helpful.  Using a single leading _ is a widely-used convention for "private" (it isn't Java-style or C++-style private).  It's conventionally "private".

Comment: That's your opinion @S.Lott

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like it's working rather too well :-)

The issue is that the assignment `self.__myvalue = ""` in `__init__` will always clobber the value of `myvalue` every time a new Borg is, er, created. You can see this if you add some additional print statements to your test:

```
conf = Config()
conf.myvalue("Hello")
print conf.myvalue()  # prints Hello
conf2 = Config()
print conf.myvalue()  # prints nothing
print conf2.myvalue() # prints nothing
```

Remove the `self.__myvalue` and things will be fine.

Having said that, the implementation of `myvalue()` is a little weird. Better, I'd say, to have explicit getters and setters using properties. You'll also want some code in `__init__` to initialize the value of `myvalue` if it doesn't exist yet, or to at least handle that it might not exist in the getter. Perhaps something like:

```
class Config(object):
    """
    Borg singleton config object
    """
    _we_are_one = {}

    def __init__(self):
        #implement the borg pattern (we are one)
        self.__dict__ = self._we_are_one

    def set_myvalue(self, val):
        self._myvalue = val

    def get_myvalue(self):
        return getattr(self, '_myvalue', None)

    myvalue = property(get_myvalue, set_myvalue)

c = Config()
print c.myvalue # prints None
c.myvalue = 5
print c.myvalue # prints 5
c2 = Config()
print c2.myvalue #prints 5
```

Comment: Ha! Fairly obvious really, should have spotted it. Thanks for the tips all.

Comment: I thought that this Borg implementation doesn't work with new-style classes. Am I missing something?

Comment: @legesh It appears to work fine in Python 2.6. Maybe I'm missing something... what info or experience gives you pause with new-style classes?

Answer (score 4):

Combining the removal of `self.__myvalue = ""` with the [new-style Borg](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/#c20) and the suggestions to avoid `__` in variable names, we get:

```
class Config(object):
    """
    Borg singleton config object
    """
    _we_are_one = {}
    _myvalue = ""

    def __new__(cls, *p, **k):
        self = object.__new__(cls, *p, **k)
        self.__dict__ = cls._we_are_one
        return self

    def myvalue(self, value=None):
        if value:
           self._myvalue = value
        return self._myvalue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = Config()
    conf.myvalue("Hello")
    conf2 = Config()
    print conf2.myvalue()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that init() is resetting myvalue to an empty string.  When I remove that line I get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Borg(object):
    """Demonstrating the Borg-pattern: All the instances of a class already
    know what one of them learned... Scary, isn't it?"""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @classmethod
    def borg_knowledge(cls, who_is_it):
        if hasattr(cls, "b_knowledge"):
            return "%s: I already know that the borg pattern is awesome!" % who_is_it
        else:
            cls.b_knowledge = True
            return "%s: Learning about the borg pattern..." % who_is_it

    def personal_experience(self):
        if hasattr(self, "p_knowledge"):
            return "%s: I already know that!" % self.name
        else:
            self.p_knowledge = True
            return "%s: Learning something..." % self.name


b1 = Borg("b1")
b2 = Borg("b2")
print ">> Created b1 and b2, both Borg"; print

print ">> Usual class behavior. One instance does not know what the other does."
print b1.personal_experience()
print b2.personal_experience()

print
print ">> Borg have a shared knowledge a.k.a. why classmethods are different!"
print b1.borg_knowledge(b1.name)
print b2.borg_knowledge(b2.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class Config:
    """
    Borg singleton config object
    """
    __we_are_one = {}
    __myvalue = ""

    def __init__(self):
        #implement the borg pattern (we are one)
        self.__dict__ = self.__we_are_one
        if self.__we_are_one:
            return
        self.__myvalue = ""

    def myvalue(self, value=None):
        if value:
           self.__myvalue = value
        return self.__myvalue

conf = Config()
conf.myvalue("Hello")    # print "Hello"
conf2 = Config()
print conf2.myvalue()    # print "Hello"
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to go along with your code. Generally we try to not simply "solve" someone's problem, but give them the tools to understand what they need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
> The problem appears to be that init() is resetting myvalue to an
> empty string. When You remove that
> line ('self.__myvalue = ""')  then you will get the expected
> output.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried implementing this using the "old-style" as well as the "new-style" and I cannot see a difference between them. Is there an advantage to one over the other? Or are these basically equivalent?

```
class Borg(object):
    shared_state = {'a_value': True}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.shared_state


class NewBorg(object):
    shared_state = {'a_value': True}

    def __new__(cls, *p, **k):
        self = object.__new__(cls, *p, **k)
        self.__dict__ = cls.shared_state
        return self


borg_a = Borg()
borg_b = Borg()

print id(borg_a), '!=', id(borg_b)
assert borg_a.shared_state == borg_b.shared_state
borg_a.shared_state['a_value'] = False
assert borg_a.shared_state == borg_b.shared_state

new_borg_a = NewBorg()
new_borg_b = NewBorg()

print id(new_borg_a), '!=', id(new_borg_b)
assert new_borg_a.shared_state == new_borg_b.shared_state
new_borg_a.shared_state['a_value'] = False
assert new_borg_a.shared_state == new_borg_b.shared_state
```